# Make PHP getcsv more strict about double quotes

Tags: php, csv

I have a file with a csv file, but for this question, I show my problem with a string. I want to validate that a certain csv file meets a number of requirements. One of them is that all fields shall be quoted using double quotes. Another one is that double quotes within a field shall be escaped by doubling the double quote character. This is shown in the code snippet below.

```
$a = 'Incorrect:ABC;"Incorrect:A"B"C";"Correct:A""B""C"';
$line = str_getcsv($a, ";", '"');
var_dump($line);
```

If I run this in [Teh Playground](http://www.tehplayground.com/#3WMRGzNaZ), I get the following result.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "Incorrect:ABC"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "Incorrect:AB"C""
  [2]=>
  string(13) "Correct:A"B"C"
}
```

1. Is there a way to make the reading of the first two fields failusing `str_getcsv` or `fgetcsv`?
2. If not, is there a way to recognize later if one of these faulty conditions occurred?

Comment: your csv looks malformed, so your csv file also contain strings like you shown here ?

Comment: What do you mean with malformed? That the first field is not quoted, and the second field has its quotes not doubled is on purpose. Are there any other malformations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with a very simple automata that checks each single line of a file:

```
<?php

  $a = 'Incorrect:ABC;"Incorrect:A"B"C";"Correct:A""B""C"';

  $state = 0;
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($a); $i++) {
    $c = $a[$i];
    if ($state == 0 && $c == "\"")
      $state = 1;
    else if ($state == 1 && $c == "\"")
      $state = 2;
    else if ($state == 2 && $c == ";")
      $state = 0;
    else if ($state == 2 && $c == "\"") // double "
      $state = 1;
    else if ($state == 1)
      $state = 1; // no-op; consume next character
    else {
      echo('Failed at character: ' . ($i + 1));
      exit();
    }
  }
  if ($state !== 2)
    echo('Line incomplete');
  else
    echo('Line OK');

?>
```